# How to center a popup in window (Windows store apps)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a custom popup (as a user control) which I load programatically. I'm not able to center it on x axis, only on vertical. The popup is not added onto an xaml file, but it is added on the root window.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Windows;
using Windows.UI.Core;

// The User Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace QSTLibrary.WIN8.Tools
{
    public sealed partial class CustomProgressRingPopup : UserControl
    {

        public CustomProgressRingPopup()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Text.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                        "Text", 
                        typeof(string), 
                        typeof(CustomProgressRingPopup),
                        new PropertyMetadata("", OnTextChanged));


        public void OpenPopup()
        {
            this.ParentPopup.IsOpen = true;
        }

        public void ClosePopup()
        {
            this.ParentPopup.IsOpen = false;
        }

        private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var instance = d as CustomProgressRingPopup;
            var newValue = e.NewValue as string;
            if (instance != null && newValue != null)
            {
                instance.CustomTextBlock.Text = newValue;
            }
        }

        private void OnPopupLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ParentPopup.HorizontalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - gdChild.ActualWidth) / 2;
            this.ParentPopup.VerticalOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height - gdChild.ActualHeight) / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

userControl xaml:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="QSTLibrary.WIN8.Tools.CustomProgressRingPopup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:QSTLibrary.WIN8.Tools"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Popup x:Name="ParentPopup" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Loaded="OnPopupLoaded">
        <Grid x:Name="gdChild" Height="auto" Width="auto" Background="Blue" Margin="20">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ProgressRing x:Name="CustomProgressRing" Height="40" Width="40" IsActive="true" Grid.Column="0" Margin="20"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="CustomTextBlock" Height="auto" Width="auto" FontSize="25" Grid.Column="1" Margin="20"/>
        </Grid>
    </Popup>    
</UserControl>
```

Here is how I use it external:

```
_loginProgressRingPopup.Text = "Logging in";
_loginProgressRingPopup.OpenPopup();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've added the LayoutUpdate callback of the popup in the cs file and works now.

```
private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
        {
            if(gdChild.ActualWidth == 0 && gdChild.ActualHeight == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            var coordinates = ParentPopup.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content).TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));            

            double ActualHorizontalOffset = ParentPopup.HorizontalOffset;
            double ActualVerticalOffset = ParentPopup.VerticalOffset;

            double NewHorizontalOffset = ((Window.Current.Bounds.Width - gdChild.ActualWidth) / 2) - coordinates.X;
            double NewVerticalOffset = ((Window.Current.Bounds.Height - gdChild.ActualHeight) / 2) - coordinates.Y;

            if (ActualHorizontalOffset != NewHorizontalOffset || ActualVerticalOffset != NewVerticalOffset)
            {
                this.ParentPopup.HorizontalOffset = NewHorizontalOffset;
                this.ParentPopup.VerticalOffset = NewVerticalOffset;
            }
        }
```

and the popup from XAML:

```
<Popup x:Name="ParentPopup" LayoutUpdated="OnLayoutUpdated">
```

Comment: "Window.Current.Bounds" was causing my app to crash with the error "Layout cycle detected.  Layout could not complete." By changing it to the Top level container I was using, it resolved it.

I also changed (NewHorizontalOffset != double.NaN && (ActualHorizontalOffset != NewHorizontalOffset || ActualVerticalOffset != NewVerticalOffset)) - to check for NaN which occurred as well.

Comment: @DaveFriedel We are facing the same problem, but are not able to implement your suggestion. 

We have a Popup within which we are using a User Control which has this code, how should we go about solving the issue so that Cycle Layout Exception is not thrown

Comment: @Teja - can you post a sample (I hate to ask that cause it is often too complex to do so)  I would recommend replacing the "Window.Current.Bounds.Width" with the name of the grid root or other object that is at the top of the stack.  I found the "WIndow" was causing my issues but if I named a wrapping object, it would work.

Comment: It appears that Windows doesn't like you adjusting layout-affecting properties inside a `LayoutUpdated` handler. I suggest using the `SizeChanged` event instead, which doesn't seem to have this problem.

Comment: also had "Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete" problem, but fixed it by casting NewHorizontal and Vertical offsets to int

Answer (score 3):

Positioning a `Popup` in a UWP Windows Store app is not as straightforward as it could be. Here is how I ended up solving it. Rather than observing the `LayoutUpdated` event (which can cause a layout cycle), observe the `SizeChanged` event of the top-level element of your view and use this to reposition the popup it is contained within.

In my case I am positioning the dialog in the center of the window, and thus use `Window.Current`. You also need to convert the coordinates, because the popup will use its own relative coordinate system based on where the `Popup` element is actually defined in your layout:

```
private void MyDialog_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    var transform = Window.Current.Content.TransformToVisual(_popup);
    Point point = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0)); // gets the window's (0,0) coordinate relative to the popup

    double hOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Width - this.ActualWidth) / 2;
    double vOffset = (Window.Current.Bounds.Height - this.ActualHeight) / 2;

    _popup.HorizontalOffset = point.X + hOffset;
    _popup.VerticalOffset = point.Y + vOffset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could center in XAML file:

```
<Popup x:Name="ParentPopup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=MainPanel}" Placement="Center" />
```

Comment: I've got the error: The property 'PlacementTarget' was not found in type 'Popup'. Same for the 'Placement'.

Comment: @AlexandruCircus the `PlacementTarget` is the Panel that you want to center. MainPanel exist by default, but you can center in another panel.

Comment: OK, I understand that. But it seems that the PlacementTarget property can not be applied to the Popup element, that's what I understand from the error: "The property 'PlacementTarget' was not found in type 'Popup'." Also, it couldn't auto-complete in code when I write Placemen... it should offer auto-complete suggestion to PlacementTarget

Comment: The project is a Windows Store apps. Maybe the PlacementTarget is not available for this kind of project. I'm a newbie in C#, .NET....I'm a java programmer

Comment: Have you tried using only `Grid` instead of `Popup`? In `OpenPopup()` method you need to set `Visibility` of `Grid`. You also didn't need to deal with offset properties of `Popup` if you use only `Grid`.

Comment: I think Popup for windows store apps does not have this prop. http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227842

Comment: PlacementTarget is part of WPF XAML, not UWP XAML.

Answer (score -1):

I modified Butzke's answer to be more universal:

```
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Placement="Center" />
```

Comment: This works for WPF but PlacementTarget and FindAncestor Mode are not available in uwp apps