# Windows universal app - Show popup grid from parent control

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, universal

I'm struggling to get something similiar to [what I painted](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/v/t34.0-12/11198788_10204946067036728_217309054_n.jpg?oh=78d92f11f4bbf24053c8051a0b294908&oe=554A092F&__gda__=1430988868_fe87a8baa6aa66ca544f9e415cb0fb03) in Photoshop (took over 9000 hours).

Basically our Windows app for tablets needs a control that shows an onscreen grid when clicked. The data genesis and grid preparation occurs in codebehind of the control and I don't know how to draw the grid outside of my control. Even simple popup control would be fine if I could get it outside the parent boundaries.

Comment: Link's dead to "what I painted" at the moment, fwiw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a flyout:

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100" Background="Black">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
            <Grid Width="200" Height="200">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" />
                    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Width="100" Height="100" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>
```

also you can prepare your own popup:

[How to center a popup in window (Windows store apps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032750/how-to-center-a-popup-in-window-windows-store-apps)